# ggplot2 plotmatrix - changing text labels

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I'm using the `plotmatrix` function in ggplot2 (ggplot2_0.8.8) and would like to override the column names displayed from my dataframe, e.g.

```
plotmatrix(mtcars) + opts(strip.text.x = theme_text(size=20))
```

I can alter the properties of strip.text.x and strip.text.y with opts, but where can I change the text itself e.g. I would like "mpg" replaced by "Miles / Gallon" which causes problems as a colname.  I assume there may be something like the `labeller` option in `facet_grid` which allows me to substitute arbitrary text for the existing colnames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the columns.

```
x <- mtcars ## just because I like x.
colnames(x)[1] <- "Miles/Gallon" ## rename all by dropping [1] and using c(...)
plotmatrix(x) + opts(strip.text.x = theme_text(size=20))
```

Comment: Yeah, creating a second temp dataframe to hold the graph data is probably the easiest way.  I was wary of screwing up references via the dataframe$colname syntax later on in the code.